# Enter key press

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net wizard template and I have a requirement like when a user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button it will be same as next button,
Some other forms i can able to manage by using defaultbutton in panel.But this case is a wizard and button are created at the time of running so i am trying to implement using jquery but still it's not working like when a user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button back button is fired, so my question is how can i change this behavior to next button insted of back button .

```
<CustomNavigationTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"  >
                            <tr align="right">
                            <td align="right" colspan="0">
                            <asp:Button ID="StepPrevButton" runat="server" data-button="true"  UseSubmitBehavior="False"  CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="Back" />
                            </td> 
                            <td align="right" >
                                <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server"  data-button="true" style= "width:120px"   
                                                CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Request User"
                                                ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />                              
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </CustomNavigationTemplate>
```

this is how the button populated

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_CreateUserWizard1_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton').length > 0) {
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_CreateUserWizard1_StartNavigationTemplateContainerID_StartNextButton").trigger('click');
            }
            else if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_CreateUserWizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton').length > 0) {
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_CreateUserWizard1_StepNavigationTemplateContainerID_StepNextButton").trigger('click');
            }
            else if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_CreateUserWizard1___CustomNav2_StepNextButton').length > 0) {
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_CreateUserWizard1___CustomNav2_StepNextButton").trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
```

there are 3 pages in my wizard

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Show the code or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some code this is quite hard to answer and most front ends are quite different.

Now taking a stab at it lets assume you are using the standard `<asp:Wizard />` control. This control has the ability to set the css classes for three different buttons that are displayed on the forms using the `CssClass` property.

The plan for implementing the logic to move the wizard forward when the  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed will use `jQuery` class selectors and `triggers` to simulate a mouse click on the `Start`, `Next` and `Finish` button.

First we start by attaching a common `css class` to each of the button types we would like to attach `jQuery` events to. The properties we are interested in are

1. `StartNextButtonStyle` -> Sets the style for the StartNext button in the wizard control.
2. `StepNextButtonStyle` -> Standard `StepNext` button used for forward navigation through the middle stages of your wizard.
3. `FinishCompleteButtonStyle` -> Finally this is the finish complete button that appears at the end.

Here is a sample of a basic wizard control with a common css class `wizard-step-button`. *note, this class doesn't need to exist in any css files as it is only used (in this case) as a jQuery selector.*

```
<asp:Wizard ID="wizard1" runat="server">
    <StartNextButtonStyle CssClass="wizard-step-btn" />
    <StepNextButtonStyle CssClass="wizard-step-btn" />
    <FinishCompleteButtonStyle CssClass="wizard-step-btn" />
</asp:Wizard>
```

You will note the property `CssClass` is set to `wizard-step-button` for each of these properties.

Now the fun part is wiring up jQuery to do the work of triggering the `Next` button click when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Here is the jQuery snippet to do just that. (Read below for explanation).

```
$(function () {
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('.wizard-step-btn:first').trigger('click');
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

In the snippet above the jQuery load event is fired (on every `PostBack` [hate that term]) and attaches to the `keyup` on the `document` object. This enables you to press enter anywhere on the document (page) to trigger the event.

Now the statement `e.keyCode == 13` checks to ensure you pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and not any other key. Finally the statement

`$('.wizard-step-btn:first').trigger('click');`

Will locate the first button that has the css class `wizard-step-btn` and will trigger the `click` event of the that button.

This essentially will perform your forward wizard navigation.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

After you posted code for the custom navigation template simply add the css 
class `wizard-step-btn` to the `StepNextButton` such as to all your next buttons.

```
<asp:Button ID="StepNextButton"
            runat="server"  
            CssClass="wizard-step-btn"
            data-button="true" 
            style= "width:120px"   
            CommandName="MoveNext" 
            Text="Request User"
            ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
```

Comment: did you do the rest of it? please elaborate 'didnt work for me'

Comment: I see you updated your question.. I updated the answer

Comment: I have my wizard created by asp:wizard and buttons are created by using 'CustomNavigationTemplate' style and i pickedup the button using  the id not css class name.<NavigationButtonStyle CssClass ="ui-wizard" />         
                    <StepNextButtonStyle  BackColor="Green"   />
                    <StartNextButtonStyle   CssClass="ui-wizard navigation-southStreet"  />
                    <StepPreviousButtonStyle BackColor="gray" />

Comment: OK, do it by css name therefore you can assign one handler to all your next buttons. Then you can avoid ID altogether. Follow the examples above and you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it fired the next button after it go back to previous button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45758/discussion-between-nico-and-user2217726)